What is the precedence of operators '=', '||'
In this command, if curl succeeds, then res will be set to the output of curl. It seems = has higher precedence than ||.
res=$(curl -s "http://example.com")||true

But || should have higher precedence than = according to this link: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html
What is going on?

There are three distinct uses of ||:

As an operator in an OR list of commands:

An OR list has the form
command1 || command2

command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns a non-zero exit status.


As an operator in the extended test construct ([[ ... ]], but not [ ... ] or test ...):

expression1 || expression2
True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.


As an operator in arithmetic contexts ($(( ... )), (( ... )), let expressions, etc.):

||
logical OR



It looks like the page you link to is talking about operators in the arithmetic contexts. However, what you are using is an OR list of commands. Here, || is a separator:

A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.

At its simplest form, a pipeline can be just a simple command. And res=$(curl -s "http://example.com") is a simple command that just results in a variable assignment. The || separates that pipeline from the other pipeline (true).
If you want to test what the linked page says, use arithmetic contexts instead, like an arithmetic expression:
$ ((a = 0 || 10 ))
$ echo $a
1
$ (((a = 0) || 10 ))
$ echo $a
0


The worst thing about that source is that doesn't appear to even try to say what context that list of operators applies to. And it happily mixes up var++, %, <, -lt, && and -a in a single list, even though as far as I can tell, there's no single context where all of them would be valid. And if we go a few sections back to 8.1, it happily talks about variable assignments, [ .. ], let and expr without ever mentioning that those are quite distinct constructs. I... wouldn't call that a very good resource.

Yes, I gave up on ABS as useful long ago. But trying to address the flaws in it seems like peeling an onion
